# html/javascript: can't pass variable to function from button?

Tags: javascript, html

the following function is in a  tag at the top of my code:

```
function textcolor(color){
  alert("Working");
  switch(color){
  case "red":
    document.body.style.background = "white";
    document.getElementbyId("content").style.color = 'red';
    break;
```

etc
when I try to make any of my buttons have onclick='textcolor()' it does the alert just fine, but when I change that to onclick='textcolor(red)' it doesn't even do the alert. when I hit f12 the console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: red is not defined", and when I mouse over the code in PHPstorm it says "Unresolved variable or type red".

Comment: You should use onclick='textcolor("red")'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to pass a `red` variable to the `textcolor` function by doing `textcolor(red)` so if you really want to pass a variable called `red` you should define oit before using it, but if you want to try to pass a simple red string you should try passing it like `'textcolor("red")'`

Comment: ok, so i have another problem: at some point I have php code that goes `echo "<input type='button' onclick='textcolor(red)' value='Red Text'>";` how would I go about putting red in quotes for this one?

Comment: Ok, when using PHP or another server side language, and you face some trouble like that, you should escape the quotes by placing slash before quote, like so `'textcolor(\'red\')`, doing like this you avoiding finish the string in PHP and putting the quote (simple or double) when escaping the character.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the text red when you click the button:

```html
<head>
    <script>
        function textcolor(color) {
            alert("Working");
            switch(color) {
                case "red":
                    document.body.style.background = "white";
                    document.getElementById('content').style.color = 'red';
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">This is a test</div>
    <button onclick='textcolor("red")'>Click me</button>
</body>
```